# Cannot include <IOStream> or it crashes

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, iostream, glut

I am using eclipse with C++ and opengl. However in my program I cannot use #include or I get the following error The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist C:\Users\workspace\mapCreator\Debug\mapCreator.exe not found

The console looks like this

> 08:10:17 ** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project
>   mapCreator ** Info: Internal Builder is used for build g++
>   "-IC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include"
>   "-IC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include-fixed"
>   "-IC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++"
>   "-IC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\backward"
>   "-IC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\mingw32"
>   "-IC:\MinGW\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o

```
"src\main.o" "..\src\main.cpp" In file included from
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/char_traits.h:41, from
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/ios:41, from
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/ostream:40, from
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/iostream:40, from
..\src\main.cpp:4:
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h: In
function 'OI std::_copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI)':
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:378:
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:378:
>   error: there are no arguments to '__is_trivial' that depend on a
>   template parameter, so a declaration of '__is_trivial' must be
>   available
>
> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:378:
>   note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but
>   allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
>
> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:383:
>   error: '__simple' cannot appear in a constant-expression
>
> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:384:
>   error: template argument 2 is invalid
>
> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h: In
>   function 'BI2 std::_copy_move_backward_a(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2)':
>   C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:573:
>   error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
>
> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:573:
>   error: there are no arguments to '__is_trivial' that depend on a
>   template parameter, so a declaration of '__is_trivial' must be
>   available
>
> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:578:
>   error: '__simple' cannot appear in a constant-expression
>
> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:579:
>   error: template argument 2 is invalid g++ -o mapCreator.exe
>
> "src\main.o" -lopengl32 -lglut32 -lglu32 g++: src\main.o: No such file
>   or directory
>
> 08:10:18 Build Finished (took 1s.31ms)

My code is just some sample code that i have been modifying and is the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int WIDTH = 600;
const int HEIGHT = 480;
void init();
void display();
void loop();
void init() {
    glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ); /* Set the clear color */
}
/* Displays a black clear screen */
void display() {
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); /* Clear the screen with the clear color */
    glutSwapBuffers(); /* Double buffering */
}



/* The main function */
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    /* Glut setup function calls */
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB ); /* Use double buffering and RGB colors */
    glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 100 );
    glutInitWindowSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
    glutCreateWindow( argv[0] );
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc( display );  /* Call back display function */
    glutMainLoop(); /* Continue drawing the scene */
    return 0;
}
```

It currently crashes, however the second that I remove #include it works fine.

Some more information:

it would appear that the .exe is not being created for some reason- i've cleaned the project and i've built it and even restarted eclipse. But it has had no effect.

[image]

[image: These errors are showing up]

I have tried running an incredibly basic program but still using iostream,GL/glut.h, and windows.h and even then it still crashes. i would assume this means that it is something wrong with the way it is set up. Code if you really need it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

cout<<"hello";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including `windows.h` after `GL/glut.h` in the first program.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not compiling != "it crashes"
2. "it would appear that the .exe is not being created for **some** reason" - how about a missing .o file? It's literally in the error messages.
3. The errors from `<iostream>` can't be caused by a *later* inclusion of anything. You stated that you tried every combination, and even showed including `<iostream>` first. Did that cause the same errors? If so, your compiler installation is broken.

Answer (score 0):

solution is simple i had the same problem however in c++
just make sure that you import the opengl library last ie

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

not

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
```

worked for me